# using ffmpeg headers with a c program

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sdl, macports

i'm trying to learn ffmpeg from drangers guide (for school), i have a mac so the first thing i did was to use Macports and get ffmpeg and sdl...

now when i'm tried to compile drangers code, the compiler didnt recognize the headers...
so i used -I on gnu when compiling, and also gave the "whole/path/name..." to the headers, 
but i always get an error on some header missing...

below i will put the code with my corrections.

i also tried including all the headers that i get an error about but there is always another header the compiler can't find

i tried both gnu (on console) and on xcode.

```
// tutorial01.c
// Code based on a tutorial by Martin Bohme (boehme@inb.uni-luebeckREMOVETHIS.de)
// Tested on Gentoo, CVS version 5/01/07 compiled with GCC 4.1.1

// A small sample program that shows how to use libavformat and libavcodec to
// read video from a file.
//
// Use
//
// gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lz
//
// to build (assuming libavformat and libavcodec are correctly installed
// your system).
//
// Run using
//
// tutorial01 myvideofile.mpg
//
// to write the first five frames from "myvideofile.mpg" to disk in PPM
// format.

#include "/opt/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "/opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void SaveFrame(AVFrame *pFrame, int width, int height, int iFrame) {
  FILE *pFile;
  char szFilename[32];
  int  y;

  // Open file
  sprintf(szFilename, "frame%d.ppm", iFrame);
  pFile=fopen(szFilename, "wb");
  if(pFile==NULL)
    return;

  // Write header
  fprintf(pFile, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);

  // Write pixel data
  for(y=0; y<height; y++)
    fwrite(pFrame->data[0]+y*pFrame->linesize[0], 1, width*3, pFile);

  // Close file
  fclose(pFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
  int             i, videoStream;
  AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx;
  AVCodec         *pCodec;
  AVFrame         *pFrame; 
  AVFrame         *pFrameRGB;
  AVPacket        packet;
  int             frameFinished;
  int             numBytes;
  uint8_t         *buffer;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Please provide a movie file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information

  // Dump information about file onto standard error
  dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, argv[1], 0);

  // Find the first video stream
  videoStream=-1;
  for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  if(videoStream==-1)
    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream

  // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
  pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

  // Find the decoder for the video stream
  pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  if(pCodec==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
    return -1; // Codec not found
  }
  // Open codec
  if(avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec)<0)
    return -1; // Could not open codec

  // Allocate video frame
  pFrame=avcodec_alloc_frame();

  // Allocate an AVFrame structure
  pFrameRGB=avcodec_alloc_frame();
  if(pFrameRGB==NULL)
    return -1;

  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                  pCodecCtx->height);
  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
  // of AVPicture
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
         pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

  // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
  i=0;
  while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, 
               packet.data, packet.size);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
    img_convert((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, 
                    (AVPicture*)pFrame, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, 
                    pCodecCtx->height);

    // Save the frame to disk
    if(++i<=5)
      SaveFrame(pFrameRGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
            i);
      }
    }

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }

  // Free the RGB image
  av_free(buffer);
  av_free(pFrameRGB);

  // Free the YUV frame
  av_free(pFrame);

  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

  // Close the video file
  av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is the error i get:                                                  In file included from tutorial01.c:1:
/opt/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:31:10: fatal error: 
      'libavutil/samplefmt.h' file not found
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav* may be useful [also possibly you need an extern C { } block around your includes]

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? This is C code linking to a C libary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to simpler includes, like:

```
#include "avcodec.h"
```

When using gcc or clang or whatever compiler, to compiler add the include directories using notation like:

```
gcc tutorial01.c -o tut -I/opt/local/include -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm
```

(I admit, I do not know if those are the correct -l params, but the general principle applies.   Use

```
-I/path/to/dir
```

to add an include directory path.)

and so on.

Comment: It should be -lavcodec not -libavcodec. Also, for ffmpeg the convention used is generally #include "libavccodec/avcodec.h". then you only need one -I/opt/local/include instead of one per library (ffmpeg has a bout a dozen libraries.

Comment: ok i got it to start compilation and only get warnings (mostly for deprecated). but now i get linker errors:

 ld: library not found for -lavformat
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is how i compile by the way:
gcc tutorial01.c -o tut -I/opt/local/include -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm
or:
$ gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm -I/opt/local/include

Comment: Make sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable includes the paths the ffmpeg libraries are installed into.  Also did you install ffmpeg with shared libraries instead of static ones? To install with the shared libraries, you need to add these two options to the `configure` program when building and installing ffmpeg: `./configure --disable-static --enable-shared`

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solved it as you said with a little help from this guide as well:  http://www.cantgetnosleep.com/wordpress/?p=111